# Error El cliente y el servidor no pueden comunicarse, ya que no poseen un algoritmo común

Tags: wpf, windows10, ssl, net

Hola a todos hice una actualización a un equipo a Windows 10 PRO 20H2 la cual tiene una aplicación de escritorio .net con wpf. (version de .net 4.8) Al intentar comunicarme con un servicio que solo soporta SSL3 me aparece un error.
Por código lo realizo de la siguiente manera

```
/*El ws no soporta tls sino ssl*/
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;

/*Como no hay certificado instalado confiar todos*/
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
```

Error que me aparece en el log de la aplicación.

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Error al enviar la solicitud. ---> System.Net.WebException: Se ha terminado la conexión: Error inesperado de recepción. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: El cliente y el servidor no pueden comunicarse, ya que no poseen un algoritmo común
   en System.Net.SSPIWrapper.AcquireCredentialsHandle(SSPIInterface SecModule, String package, CredentialUse intent, SecureCredential scc)
   en System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.AcquireCredentialsHandle(CredentialUse credUsage, SecureCredential& secureCredential)
   en System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.AcquireClientCredentials(Byte[]& thumbPrint)
   en System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.GenerateToken(Byte[] input, Int32 offset, Int32 count, Byte[]& output)
   en System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.NextMessage(Byte[] incoming, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   en System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   en System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   en System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   en System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   en System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   en System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   en System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result)
   en System.Net.TlsStream.BeginWrite(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState)
   en System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean async)
   --- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la excepción interna ---
   en System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult, TransportContext& context)
   en System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
   --- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la excepción interna ---
   en System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   en Kiosco.Helpers.LoggedClient.<Post>d__3.MoveNext() |    en System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   en Kiosco.Helpers.LoggedClient.<Post>d__3.MoveNext()
```

Error en los eventos del sistema
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: SSLv3 es un algoritmo deprecado e inseguro. Esto posiblemente derive de actualizaciones que lo han desactivado como opción en el servidor. No deberían usarlo.